# Derive Tutte's (1-factor) theorem from Mader's (independent path) theorem

Tags: graph-theory

This is an exercise from Chapter 3 of Diestel's 'Graph Theory' book, and all my attempts have shown below (following the hints from both behind the problem and attached at the end of the book):

The first observation: $$q(G-S)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum C-\sum\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}|C|\right\rfloor\right)=|G|-|S|-2\sum\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}|C|\right\rfloor,$$
where the sum takes over connected components of $G-S$.

We need to find a set $S\subset V(G)$ that violates Tutte's condition, i.e. $S$ satisfies that
$$q(G-S)>|S|,$$
which is equivalent to $$\frac{|G|}{2}>|S|+\sum\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}|C|\right\rfloor.$$

That's where I stuck since in Mader's theorem the term in summation is $\lfloor|\partial C|/2\rfloor$ so that we desire a stronger inequality.

The hint in the book says:

Construct a new graph $G'=(V',E')$, where $$V'=\{v,v':v\in V(G)\}=V\sqcup H,\quad E'=E\cup\bigcup_{V(G)}\{(v,v')\}$$

Then there are at most $|V(G)|/2$ independent $H-$path in $G'$.  When the upper bound reaches, it is clear that $G$ has a 1-factor. And construct the set $S$ that violates Tutte's condition whenever the upper bound is strict based on the set $X\subset V(G), F\subset E(G)$ in the theorem stated below.

Mader's Theorem (1978)
(Chapter 3 section 4 of Diestel's book)

Define $$M_G(H)=\min\left(|X|+\sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C}_{F}}\lfloor|\partial C|/2\rfloor\right),$$
where $H$ is an induced subgraph of $G$, $X\subset V(G-H)$ and $F\subset E(G-H-X)$ such that any $H-$path in $G$ have a vertex of an edge in $X\cap F$, and $\mathcal{C}_F$ denotes the set of components in $V(G-H-X)$ whose edge set is $F$.

Mader's theorem states that there are exactly $M_G(H)$ independent $H-$paths in $G$, which is also a strict upper bound.

Comment: There are a lot of theorems under the name "Mader's theorem". Can you add the statement to the question? (It wouldn't hurt to add Tutte's theorem as well, but that's less ambiguous).

Comment: @DánielG. I have added the theorem and its statement to the question. If my poor English baffles your understanding, GTM173 is the exact reference, where you will find a better one in section 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the graph $G'$ by adding a vertex $v'$ for every vertex $v \in V(G)$, and connect $v$ to $v'$. Let $H = \{v'| v \in V(G)\}$.

**Observation 1.** $H$ has $\frac{|G|}{2}$ independent $H$-paths if and only if $G$ has one factor.

Suppose Tutte's condition is satisfied, that is, $q(G - S) \leq |S|$ for every $S \subseteq V(G)$. Consider $M_{H}(G') = \min (|X| + \sum_{c\in \mathcal{C}_F} \lfloor \frac{1}{2}|\partial C | \rfloor)$.

We have $|\partial C| \geq |C|$ for every $C \in \mathcal{C}_F$. Since $C \subseteq G' - H - X$, then every vertex $v$ in $C$ has a neighbour $v'$ in $H$.
Therefore,
$$|X| + \sum_{c\in \mathcal{C}_F} \lfloor \frac{1}{2} |\partial C| \rfloor \geq |X| + \sum_{c\in \mathcal{C}_F} \lfloor \frac{1}{2} |C| \rfloor  $$

Since every component of $\mathcal{C}_F$ is a component of $G' - X$. We get,
$$\sum_{c\in \mathcal{C}_F} \lfloor \frac{1}{2} |C| \rfloor   = \frac{|G|}{2} - \frac{|X|}{2} - \frac{q(G - X)}{2}.$$

Therefore,
$$|X| + \sum_{c\in \mathcal{C}_F} \lfloor \frac{1}{2} |C| \rfloor \geq \frac{|X|}{2} - \frac{q(G - X)}{2} + \frac{|G|}{2} \geq \frac{|G|}{2}.$$

The last inequality follows from Tutte's condition $(|X| \geq q(G - X))$, and by observation 1, we have 1-factor for $G$.

Every component of $\mathcal{C}_F$ is a component of $G' - X$ because every vertex in $G'-X - H$ must be in a component, suppose it is not the case, then consider a vertex $v$, all its neighbours must be in a component otherwise we found a path not covered by $F$, by adding $v$ we decrease the size of the boundary by $d(v) - 1$ if $d(v)> 1$ then $F$ contradict the minimality of $M_H(G')$.